# Mysql query to get count per months and year using entry date and outing date

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table collaborator that contains:
the columns : hiring_date and release_date ( date type)
i would like to calculate the total number of collaborators per month of a year 
using hiring_date and release_date

Comment: what you tried so far . show your query

Comment: You're going to need to give us more information than this.  Please show some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking for something like this but please, try to give more information when asking

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM collaborator WHERE hiring_date >= date AND release_date<= date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "GROUP BY" for this.
e.g., To calculate the total number of collaborators per month using hiring_date :

```
SELECT MONTH(hiring_date),COUNT(*) FROM `collaborator`
GROUP BY MONTH(hiring_date);
```

---

To calculate the total number of collaborators per month of a year using release_date, use :

```
SELECT MONTH(release_date),COUNT(*) FROM `collaborator `
GROUP BY MONTH(release_date)
WHERE YEAR(release_date) = <year>;
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is to get number of hiring collaborators on 2016 per month

```
   SELECT  
    SUM(IF(month = '1', total, 0)) AS 'Jan',
        SUM(IF(month = '2', total, 0)) AS 'Feb',
        SUM(IF(month = '3', total, 0)) AS 'Mar',
        SUM(IF(month = '4', total, 0)) AS 'Apr',
        SUM(IF(month = '5', total, 0)) AS 'May',
        SUM(IF(month = '6', total, 0)) AS 'Jun',
        SUM(IF(month = '7', total, 0)) AS 'Jul',
        SUM(IF(month = '8', total, 0)) AS 'Aug',
        SUM(IF(month = '9', total, 0)) AS 'Sep',
        SUM(IF(month = '10', total, 0)) AS 'Oct',
        SUM(IF(month = '11', total, 0)) AS 'Nov',
        SUM(IF(month = '12', total, 0)) AS 'Dec'

     FROM (
    SELECT month(DATE_ENTREE) AS month , count(DATE_ENTREE) as total
    FROM collaborateur where YEAR(DATE_ENTREE) =2016
    GROUP BY month(DATE_ENTREE)) as e
```

and this code is the number of release per month on 2016

```
SELECT  
SUM(IF(month = '1', total, 0)) AS 'Jan',
    SUM(IF(month = '2', total, 0)) AS 'Feb',
    SUM(IF(month = '3', total, 0)) AS 'Mar',
    SUM(IF(month = '4', total, 0)) AS 'Apr',
    SUM(IF(month = '5', total, 0)) AS 'May',
    SUM(IF(month = '6', total, 0)) AS 'Jun',
    SUM(IF(month = '7', total, 0)) AS 'Jul',
    SUM(IF(month = '8', total, 0)) AS 'Aug',
    SUM(IF(month = '9', total, 0)) AS 'Sep',
    SUM(IF(month = '10', total, 0)) AS 'Oct',
    SUM(IF(month = '11', total, 0)) AS 'Nov',
    SUM(IF(month = '12', total, 0)) AS 'Dec'

 FROM (
SELECT month(DATEE_SORTIE_COLLABORATEUR) AS month , count(DATEE_SORTIE_COLLABORATEUR) as total
FROM collaborateur where YEAR(DATEE_SORTIE_COLLABORATEUR) =2016
GROUP BY month(DATEE_SORTIE_COLLABORATEUR)) as s
```

my objective is to calculate total number of collaborator per month 
hope this can help you to understand what i mean